# AWS Glue JOB to get secret value from secretmanager

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-secrets-manager, aws-glue-connection

I'm working on the AWS glue job, can someone please help me to give me a script in AWS Glue Job Spark that would retrieve my secrets from secret manager. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly simple (if you have all of the required IAM permissions) using boto3 and [get_secret_value()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/secretsmanager.html#SecretsManager.Client.get_secret_value) function.

```
sm_client = boto3.client('secretsmanager')
response = sm_client.get_secret_value(
    SecretId=<your_secret_id>
)
```

If the value is a string, you can extract it like this:

```
value = secret_value_response['SecretString']
```

If it is a binary value:

```
secret_value_response['SecretBinary']
```

Additionally, if the secret has multiple versions of the secret, you have to use `VersionId` and/or `VersionStage` as explained in the linked documentation.